# Select columns by looping

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table in SQL Server 2005 with a variable number of columns, the first two being the only ones which are constant. 
I've managed to get the number of columns in the table, so I would have what to count up to, but I don't really know how to select a variable number of columns.

```
SELECT
DISTINCT
COUNT(*)
FROM
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.[COLUMNS]
WHERE
TABLE_NAME = 'SOME_TABLE'
AND
(COLUMN_NAME <> 'STATIC_COL1' AND COLUMN_NAME <> 'STATIC_COL2')
```

I'm guessing I need to use a while loop to get each column.
Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Edit:
I ended up using @aF's suggestion of dynamic SQL (see below)

```
DECLARE @CMD  AS VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @CMD = 'SELECT '
DECLARE @COL AS VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE COLUMN_CURSOR CURSOR FOR
SELECT
COLUMN_NAME
FROM
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.[COLUMNS]
WHERE
TABLE_NAME = 'SOME_TABLE'

OPEN COLUMN_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM COLUMN_CURSOR
INTO @COL
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

IF @COL = 'STATIC_COL1'
BEGIN
SET @CMD = @CMD + @COL
END

FETCH NEXT FROM COLUMN_CURSOR
INTO @COL

SET @CMD = @CMD + ', CAST(' + @COL +' AS INT) AS ' + @COL

END
CLOSE COLUMN_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE COLUMN_CURSOR

SET @CMD = @CMD + ' FROM SOME_TABLE'

EXEC (@CMD)
```

Comment: "I have a table in SQL Server 2005 with a variable number of columns" - o rly?

Comment: Can you clarify what your end goal is? Are you wanting to loop round each column, and for what purpose?

Comment: @Mark over the lifetime of the table, perhaps...

Comment: @Mark ya rly. The table is created as the result of a pivot that's done on a list of active projects. As such, when a new project is added, the number of columns in the table will change because the table is dropped and recreated daily.

Comment: @Greyhound: Is there a reason for not running a pivot query against the active projects as required, instead of rebuilding the result table every day?

Comment: @AdaTheDev the end goal is to convert the datatype of the variable columns upon selecting them.

Comment: @MarkBannister the reason for not running a pivot query every time is that it takes too long to run, so placing the result in a table reduces the query to a simple select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it:

The following select gives you the list of columns:

```
SELECT
column_name
FROM
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.[COLUMNS]
WHERE
TABLE_NAME = 'SOME_TABLE'
AND
(COLUMN_NAME <> 'STATIC_COL1' AND COLUMN_NAME <> 'STATIC_COL1')
```

With that, you can construct the intended query and use dynamic SQL to execute it.

Dynamic SQL is something like this:

```
declare @cmd = 'select * from some_table'
exec(@cmd)
```

In you case, you need to construct the `@cmd` with the columns from the first select.

Comment: That worked beautifully! Thank you. 
`DECLARE @CMD  AS VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @CMD = 'SELECT '
DECLARE @COL AS VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE COLUMN_CURSOR CURSOR FOR
SELECT
COLUMN_NAME
FROM
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.[COLUMNS]
WHERE
TABLE_NAME = 'SOME_TABLE'

OPEN COLUMN_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM COLUMN_CURSOR
INTO @COL
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

 IF @COL = 'STATIC_COL1'
 BEGIN
 SET @CMD = @CMD + @COL
 END

 FETCH NEXT FROM COLUMN_CURSOR
 INTO @COL

 SET @CMD = @CMD + ', CAST(' + @COL +' AS INT) AS ' + @COL
 
END
CLOSE COLUMN_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE COLUMN_CURSOR

SET @CMD = @CMD + ' FROM SOME_TABLE'

EXEC (@CMD)`